# Quadrapole moment of a real dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

What is the quadrapole moment of a real dipole with 2 opposite charges seperated by distance $a$?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1):

So the quadrupolemoment can be defined as:
$$Q=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}q_ir_i^2(3cos^2(\theta_i)-1)$$

imagine having one charge q in $x=\frac{a}{2}$ and one charge -q in $x=\frac{-a}{2}$, then we find:

$$Q=\frac{1}{2}\left( q \frac{a^2}{4}2-q\frac{a^2}{4}2 \right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The quadrupole moment is
$$Q_{ij}=\int(3x'_i x'_j-r'^2 \delta_{ij})\rho(\vec{r}')d\tau'$$
Let us put the dipole to be along the z-direction centered at the origin.

For a real dipole,
$$Q_{ij}=q(3x^+_i x^+_j-{r^+}^2 \delta_{ij})-q(3x^-_i x^-_j-{r^-}^2 \delta_{ij})=3q(x^+_i x^+_j - x^-_i x^-_j)=0$$

The dipole moment is zero. The leading order should probably be octupole.

Comment: But can quadrapole moment exist if quadrapole potential is 0 ?

Comment: If the quadrupole potential is identically zero, then the quadrupole moment must be zero.